# Why do I get the error in MS Word 2007 "Word cannot create a new, blank form" when I try to start a Collect Signatures workflow?

Tags: workflow, error, word, digital-signature

The rest of the error message is: "One or more required custom controls in this form cannot be created".

I also get this message when clicking the Edit This Task button on the Workflow Task toolbar in MS Word 2007 when I am part of a Collect Feedback workflow.

I do not understand even what the form is it is talking about. Has any of you guys experienced this?

We have SharePoint 2010 and MS Office 2007.

Also see [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/450b49a6-aad5-4371-b504-52b8cea7a755).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to repair the Microsoft Office installation.